# Date and Time jframe GUI

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, swingx

i'm trying to include in my GUI a date/time picker. How can i do this?. Could someone tell me or give me a link to a tutorial?.

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339354/what-are-good-java-date-chooser-swing-gui-widgets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a Date Picker inside Swing SDK. So you should implement the date picker  by yourself, or use a third party.

Please check this [tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/swing/datePicker.html) for implementing one.
You can also use a open source third party like [JCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/).

Comment: There is indeed no standard date picker. Ofcourse you can implement one yourself, or you can find date pickers that others have implemented on the web; check if you can find one that suits your needs and that you can use (check the license).