# Determine if String entered by user is in the proper format

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to check if a String is entered by the user in a specific format.
I cannot use SimpleDateFormat, catch, split or anything along those lines since I have not learned it. I'm at a very novice level and have learned how to use and manipulate Strings.
The user is to enter mm/dd/yyyy (I'm using JOptionPane) so it is a String. I've pulled the month, day, and year as sub-strings (and converted to integers for another use). However, everything goes wrong if it is entered m/dd/yy. Since people can't be trusted to follow directions, I need something to catch incorrect entries.
I have learned about Gregorian Calendar, but not sure that will help. In the end I need to use arrays to turn mm/dd/yyyy to MMM/dd/yyyy. So I was going to first check that the entry was valid, then convert to integers and use the number to coincide with the month array, then make sure the day is within the number of days in the month. Finally, I need to give the day in the year it is and that is why I parsed(?) to integers. Everything else works as long as the user enters it properly. Feel free to suggest any other edits. I did try to use an object, but had a very difficult time with it so changed to a parallel array.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ConvertDate
{
    public static void main(String[] agrs)
{

        int numOfDay;
        String date, mnthName = "";
        int monthNumber, dayNumber, yearNumber;
        String month = "", day = "", year = "";
        int validDays = 31;

        int monthNum[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
        String[] monthName = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}; 
        int[] daysInMonth = {31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

        date = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a date. Use format mm/dd/yyy");
        month = date.substring(0, 2);
        day = date.substring(3, 5);
        year = date.substring(6, 10);
        yearNumber = Integer.parseInt(year);
        monthNumber =  Integer.parseInt(month);
        dayNumber = Integer.parseInt(day);

        for(int x = 0; x < 12; x++)
        {
            if(monthNumber == monthNum[x])
            {
                mnthName = monthName[x];
                validDays = daysInMonth[x];
            }
        }

        GregorianCalendar dayOfYear = new GregorianCalendar(yearNumber, (monthNumber - 1), dayNumber);
        numOfDay = dayOfYear.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

        if(dayNumber > validDays || dayNumber < 0 || monthNumber < 0 || monthNumber > 12)
// if(!date.equals("**/**/****"))  does not work, nor if(!date.equals(**"/"**"/"****))
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid date or invalid format.");
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mnthName + " " + dayNumber + ", " + year + " is \nthe " + numOfDay + " day of the year.");

    }       
}
```

Comment: Learn to use those things.

Comment: The effort you are spending trying to solve this like this would be much better spent learning to use split, try/catches, or SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: I understand. However, I am trying to stay within what has been covered up to now. I was also trying `if(... month.lenght() != 2...)` but it will see 6/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `if(year.length != 4)` Since if the date was entered in any other way it would result in something other than 4 characters. I also changed it to get the characters at the "/" so they can't enter 6//23/2013 (which would result in 4 year characters).

Answer (score 1):

you can use Regex to check if the input of users match the format you want.

date = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a date. Use format mm/dd/yyy");
boolean bool = data.match("[0-9]{2}//[0-9]{2}//[0-9]{4}");

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that separate all three values with `split` method of String by delimeter `"\"` it will help you if user enter 1 instead of 01 and likewise for dd and mm format. Now assign this values to respective date, month and year variables.

This is because try entering 1/1/2013 which should be a valid date with valid format, here you are using substring functionality which results in value 1/1/2013 to throw java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Now validate your values to be month in between Jan to Dec and days in between 1 to 31 according to month i.e January can have 31 days, April can have 30 and so on.

Moreover do validate year with leap year functionality.

I would also suggest you to make some functions/methods to modularize your code.

Comment: I would also suggest that if you are used to with regular expression than it would surely remove your problems and easily solve your question

Answer (score 0):

The best way to ensure it's in the proper format is to not allow the user to enter free-form text -- use a date picker instead (calender, drop-down menus, etc).

Here's a discussion of some Java date pickers:
[What are good Java date-chooser Swing GUI widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339354/what-are-good-java-date-chooser-swing-gui-widgets)