# How to create a date picker in java?

Tags: java, swing, date, calendar, frame

I am trying to code my own date picker for learning purposes.

The type in which a calendar popup is displayed and we can pick a date.

I have no idea what that thing is called. Is it a Jframe without a window?

What is it and how can it be displayed without things like regular swing frame or popup?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are good Java date-chooser Swing GUI widgets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339354/what-are-good-java-date-chooser-swing-gui-widgets)

Comment: you can check out [**this**](http://netbeans.dzone.com/articles/creating-datepicker-control)

Comment: it is not a duplicate.. the guy wants to knw how to create his own datepicker he is not asking for widgets..

Comment: No sorry you got me wrong, I do not want to "use" a picker. I want to code "my own picker"

Comment: have you started coding..? if you could show us what you have done so far and what you have in mind, we would be glad to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by using a `JFrame` and calling `setUndecorated(true)` on it.

**Example code:**

```
// Left image
frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(new JButton("Decorated"));

// Right image
frame2 = new JFrame();
frame2.setUndecorated(true);
frame2.add(new JButton("Undecorated"));
```

**Result:**

[image: results]

The other frame can then be closed when a date is picked. It can also be canceled by adding a click listener to the parent frame and closing the frame there, or adding a window state listener for closing the picker frame as soon as it loses focus.

Comment: IIRC, you can also do an undecorated JDialog.

Answer (score 1):

In the JDatePicker project you can find an example of this:

```
PopupFactory fac = new PopupFactory();
Point xy = getLocationOnScreen();
datePanel.setVisible(true);
popup = fac.getPopup(this, datePanel, (int) xy.getX(), (int) (xy.getY()+this.getHeight()));
popup.show();
```

Check in the source:

https://github.com/JDatePicker/JDatePicker/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jdatepicker/impl/JDatePickerImpl.java#L182